# Complete Dispose Resources in VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a simple winform application in VB.NET 2008 Express Edition. 
In this form I use a UserControl that load picture thumbnail from a temporary directory. I try to delete the temporary directory after closing the form. I dispose the control and delete the directory. But it always show a error screen that the first image is used by the application. How could I dispose all the resources.
Main form code: `pastebin.com/wrz0gKG0`
Password Check:(just contains a single button) `pastebin.com/dNXcn8mx`
ThumbnailGenerate Code: `pastebin.com/CAvCx1dL`
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1xCf.jpg)

My code is

```
Private Sub Main_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    ThumbnailGenerate1.Dispose()
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(appPath & "\data\tmp", True)
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur? I think you're going to have to provide a [mcve] for us to answer this.

Comment: Show us all the code that opens an image file or closes and image file.  Clearly there is a file that you're opening and not closing.

Comment: Also, why are you calling `Application.Exit` in the `FormClosing` event handler?  Isn't the application already existing if you're in that handler to begin with? I wonder whether that might even be causing the issue.

Comment: There is a password check form, after password check it opens the main form and hide the password check form. That's why I use Application Exit.

Comment: Main form code:
http://pastebin.com/wrz0gKG0
Password Check:(just contains a single button)
http://pastebin.com/dNXcn8mx
ThumbnailGenerate Code:
http://pastebin.com/CAvCx1dL

Comment: try setting all the references to the image to null, including the picturebox's Image property.

Comment: Can you please tell me from I can set the image reference to null?